# Wayland not working Kali linux KDE 2019

Tags: linux, kde, gui, wayland

I am having an issue with kali linux KDE edition, in which it will boot into GUI, but after dist-upgrade it won't boot into GUI anymore. I had this problem previously on the gnome edition, which I fixed by cd'ing into `/etc/gdm3`, using nano on the `daemon.conf` file and uncommenting the `WaylandEnable = false` variable, after which it would boot into the gnome desktop.

Could this be graphics drivers? How can I turn off Wayland in KDE?

I am still a novice user but I like to learn through doing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: *I am still a novice user* and Kali is never a good idea. *How can I turn off Wayland in KDE?* You don't need to? Just boot to Xorg instead, I'm sure you can select before logging in.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Comment: Cheers for the link

Comment: The point is that nobody uses Kali to do actual work where you'd need KDE, Gnome, or Wayland. No matter what you read on some forums, where apparently people tell newbies "Kali is what all the experts use". Kali is used for penetration testing, not on your Desktop/Laptop, not even by experts. Just switch to a proper distro intended for daily use, and all your problems are solved.  Kali is Debian-based, so another Debian-based distro is the obvious choice. And you'll also have all the hacker tools Kali has.

Answer (score -1):

As someone that pen tests for a living I have to say you are very wrong.  You said *"The point is that nobody uses Kali to do actual work where you'd need KDE, Gnome, or Wayland. No matter what you read on some forums"*  Do you think that all pen test tools are run from the command line?  Not so.  There is a ton of tools on Kali which are GUI based and must be run from a desktop.  Especially web hacking its hard to attack a site without a browser.

I do agree for the normal Linux user Kali is not a good choice.  If you want to play around with Kali load it up on a USB and run it from there.  Even using this method you will need a desktop to run a lot of the tools.

Still some of us that do this every day do run Kali as our default install.  We add a normal user account for like writing on this forum and doing normal stuff and then login as root for testing only.

Setting up a normal user account and running Kali from there is no different than any other Debian install and just as secure.

KDE is known to break on Kali due to the KDE devs hardcoding root blocks and not using config files to block root access on normal Linux installs.

If you are going to use Kali best to use XFCE.

Yes I am an expert I have been doing this for over 20 years.